# what kind of moving average will be drawn when we use (mpl.finance mav) function

Tags: mplfinance

My question is when we use mplfinance mpf.plot function to draw candlestick and use the mav function to draw the moving average. What kind of moving average it is? Is it Exponential moving average or simple moving average?

```
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(daily,type='candle',mav=(20),volume=True, style='blueskies',returnfig=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mplfinance `mpf.plot(data,...,mav=...)` does a simple moving average (although it also allows for a shift in the moving average).

[The code for the moving average is here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/plotting.py#L1084-L1117).

Specifically, the actual calulation is [on this line of code](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/plotting.py#L1107).

It should not be very difficult to modify the code to allow for other types of moving averages, particually if you want to contribute.

That said, in the menatime, alternative moving averages can be calulated externally and [plotted with `mpf.make_addplot()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb).

Comment: P.S.  I am the maintainer of mplfinance.  It should be relatively easy to modify the mplfinance code to calculate any of SMA, CMA, and EMA.  If you are interested in contributing this enhancement I will be pleased to guide you through the process (if you are not already familiar with it).

Comment: Hi! Dan, Thanks for notes. In fact I was expecting something from you only :) . Sure, I would like to contribute and I am not aware of process. I am loving Python with Financial packages. Please share the process and other details.

Comment: @Dharmesh  Please take a look at https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md and make sure you are familiar with the **Fork Clone workflow**.  When you are, you can either email me at dgoldfarb.github@gmail.com or you can post a note to the enhancement issue here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/506 and I will then follow up with any guidance, if needed, related to the moving average enhancement.

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb thank you  for such amazing python lib, I am attempting to resolve the following: instead of an SMA or EMA, I need to add a MACD on a Renko graph, the MACD data have been created from mpf.plot.return_calculated_values using then all the "Close" prices,  is there a lecture or any hint you could share